# Excel 2013 VB to re-calculate data entry value on exit from cell?

Tags: excel, formula, calculation, vba

I have a spreadsheet, where I need to manually enter values from external sources.
For 3 of these cells, there is a decimal value:
ex:  66.78, 28.5, 0.5171

I would like to be able to enter the digits (without the decimal) and, on exiting the cell, have VB code do the appropriate division for each column (but without duplicating the division if later edited...).

That is: type in 6678, and as cursor moves to next cell, the VB divides it by 100.  Type in 285, the VB divides this one by 10.  Then the next one is divided by 10000.

Brute force solution is to enter the integers elsewhere, and have a division formula where I want the decimal values.  But, similar to code I have for one cell's text to turn UPPERCASE when leaving the cell, I expect there's a way to run a code fragment on a cell's numeric value - here's the uppercase code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("$D11:$D$110")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        With Target
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

To avoid duplication, if editing the original value, the ideal would be like:

"on_exit cell, if cell.value > 100, then X/100, else X" for the first one.

I'm hoping there's some minor tweak to the

```
.Value = UCase(.Value)
```

snippet that will do numeric calculation.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the logic behind the division?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You can just modify the code you have to do the division, depending on the cell.  And to prevent the code from running if there's already something there, use the selection_change event to capture the value in the cell before you enter anything.